# How can I get data out of onDataChange method?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Situation**: I want to compare a *url* from my function parameter with a *url* retrieved from my firebase realtime database. The retrieval works, however, I don't know how else to get a boolean value from the String comparison in my if-else statement, in which I get an error of: "Cannot assign value to final variable 'bool' ".

*compare() code*:

```
private boolean compare(String url) {
    mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Executive Branch");
    final String newUrl = url;
    final boolean bool = false;

    mDatabaseReference.limitToFirst(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ExecutiveOrder executiveOrder = snapshot.getValue(ExecutiveOrder.class);
                    if (executiveOrder.getUrl().equals(newUrl)) {
                        bool = true;
                    } else {
                        bool = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("Executive Order", "The read failed: " + databaseError.getDetails());
        }
    });

    return bool;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign a final variable a new value.

And if you are gonna access outer class variables inside inner class they have to declared final.

One simple but not elegant way is to declare an boolean array of size 1.

```
mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Executive Branch");
final String newUrl = url;
final boolean[] bool = new boolean[1];   //boolean array of size 1

mDatabaseReference.limitToFirst(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ExecutiveOrder executiveOrder = snapshot.getValue(ExecutiveOrder.class);
                if (executiveOrder.getUrl().equals(newUrl)) {
                    bool[0] = true;   //access the bool value like this
                } else {
                    bool[0] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e("Executive Order", "The read failed: " + databaseError.getDetails());
    }
});
```

By the way you are making a big mistake. Your code is gonna return false all the time.

Firebase database methods are Asynchronous meaning they are executed in a separate thread so we cannot determent when they data will be retrieved from the database. It depends upon the speed of your internet.

So you have to call the appropriate method inside the `onDataChange` method. Example ...

```
private boolean compare(String url) {
    mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Executive Branch");
    final String newUrl = url;

    mDatabaseReference.limitToFirst(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ExecutiveOrder executiveOrder = snapshot.getValue(ExecutiveOrder.class);
                    boolean bool = executiveOrder.getUrl().equals(newUrl);
                    doSomething(bool); //This method will handle the logic
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("Executive Order", "The read failed: " + databaseError.getDetails());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error told you what is the problem. You are trying to assign value to a final variable. Try to return true or false directly. But please notice that firebase calls are asynchronous, which means it may return the default value at the bottom of your method.

```
private boolean compare(String url) {
    mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Executive Branch");
    final String newUrl = url;
    final boolean bool;

    mDatabaseReference.limitToFirst(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ExecutiveOrder executiveOrder = snapshot.getValue(ExecutiveOrder.class);
                    if (executiveOrder.getUrl().equals(newUrl)) {
                        bool = true;
                    } else {
                        bool = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("Executive Order", "The read failed: " + databaseError.getDetails());
        }
    });

    if(bool!=null)        < Add a condition to check if bool is null or not
    return bool;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: Cannot return true or false from a method of void result type though

Comment: Do you know any other possible way to return true or false?

Comment: I changed my answer, it should be fine now. But i recommend you to do the firebase retrieval in advance so you don't need to block or wait for the result.

Answer (score 0):

Make the variable `bool` a global variable in your class and remove the `final` keyword so that you can both read and write the value from anywhere inside the methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use variable out of the method onDataChange, write all the process you want to do with that variable in a method out of the onDataChange. This method should have a String as parameter(because we mostly receive value from firebase as a string). Now, call this method in onDataChange method and pass the variable of onDataChange as an argument to this method.

for example:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   String firebaseVariable=dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
   methodToProcess(firebaseVariable);
}

methodToProcess(String firebaseVariable){
//Your processing here
}
```